# MLPRegressor predictions have upper and lower bounds

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm pretty new to machine learning but I'm trying to use MLPRegressor from scikit-learn to model data that has 4 inputs and 1 output. The data set has more inputs and outputs than that, but I believe I have chosen the only ones that are applicable to the output I've chosen. I have around 60,000 samples in the data set. The model learns most of the data but seems to have an upper and lower bound on the outputs.

I've tried many different combinations of hyperparameters but none of them have gotten rid of the apparent bounds on the outputs. I have tried normalizing the data but it didn't really help. For this particular set of hyperparameters, the loss is 106.555 and the score on both the training and testing data is 0.998.

Here is the code:

```
# Importing the data from a .csv file
input_cols = [3,4,7,9]
output_cols = [8]
X, y, all_data = [], [], []
with open(data_path, 'r') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    i = 0
    for line in reader:
        try:
            a = [float(line[3]), float(line[4]), float(line[7]), float(line[10])]
            b = [float(line[9])]
            X.append(a)
            y.append(b)
        except ValueError:
            print('ValueError')
    all_data = [X, y]
print('Done importing data')

# Splitting the data for training and testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state = 42)

# Training the neural network
model = MLPRegressor(max_iter=10**4, verbose=True, hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10,10), tol=0.00001, learning_rate_init=0.005, random_state=1, \
                     activation='logistic', solver='adam')
print('Beginning training')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Training complete')

# Results
winsound.PlaySound('C:/Windows/media/Windows Background.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
print('Score on training data: {:.3f}'.format(model.score(X_train, y_train)))
print('Score on testing data: {:.3f}'.format(model.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

Below are plots of the results. Each plot is one of the 4 inputs plotted on the x-axis and the output on the y-axis. Red is the network's prediction, blue is the actual data. I have to remove the axes for privacy reasons, but know that the y-axis ranges from about -700 to 700.
[Results plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9arGB.png)

Comment: Getting networks to extrapolate can be a challenge, one possible solution, [as explained here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110026/can-neural-net-extrapolate-output-value), is to use ReLu activations.